# NLog Configuration File reset after publish

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.0 project that, when I publish, will replace my carefully crafted NLog configuration file with what appears to be a empty default file devoid of targets or my variables. I am not sure what is causing this behavior. Has anyone else run into this, and if so, found out what was causing it?

I can of course always update my Nlog config after publishing it with a saved copy, but I find that process to be too error prone. Someone on the team is going to forget and we will lose our critical logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably using  the NLog.Config package. That package isn't compatible with the package reference style in the csproj files.

This is documented on [the nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nlog.config)

> Note: Unfortunately this package won't work well when using `<PackageReference>`

> Advised to:
>
> - download manually: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NLog/NLog/dev/src/NuGet/NLog.Config/content/NLog.config
> - set "Copy To Output Directory" to "Copy if newer"

Comment: I am using Nlog.Config as a matter of fact. I wasn't expecting that it would display this behavior. In older asp.net it was basically just a download of an XML file. I will try removing this NuGet package and seeing if that changes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Nlog 4.7.13, fixed it by reverting to v 4.3.4 (maybe some new version that's before 4.7.13 doesn't have this problem, I just wanted to be safe, since in the link below some users said to face this problem in v 4.5.x)

see this issue for more:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2823